# PHP 8.1 var is declared in class and value to this var assigned in function but value is not available

Tags: php, web

I'm trying to implement a contact form for a website running on PHP 8.1 and found some useful PHP scripts which seem to be outdated by now, though. I've refactored it as best as I can but I still get an error saying "imagecreate(): Argument #1 ($width) must be greater than 0". Here is the code

```
class FGCaptchaCreator extends FG_CaptchaHandler
{
    var $image;
    var $width;
    var $height;
    var $margin_y;
    var $charset;
    var $nChars;
    var $linecolor;
    var $code;
    var $show_captcha_var;
    var $nlines;
    var $enc_key;
    var $captcha_var_name;

    function FGCaptchaCreator($captcha_var_name)
    {
        $this->width = 150;
        $this->height= 60;
        $this->charset="2356789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        $this->nChars=6;
        $this->margin_y = 10;

        $this->nlines = 2;
        $this->font_file = 'include/SFOldRepublicSCBold.ttf';
        $this->enc_key="GhsnR5^Hyhsfg";
        $this->captcha_var_name = $captcha_var_name;
 
   }
...
}
```

The error is thrown in this function

```
function Create()
    {
        $this->image = imagecreate($this->width, $this->height);
        imagecolorallocate($this->image, 255, 255, 255);

        $this->code = $this->CreateCode();
        return true;
    }
```

I've tried assigning the value in the first declaration instead of in the function, but I and the captcha image displays correctly but I want to know how to do it "properly".

Comment: Is the Create function part of the class? `$test` is only valid inside the class. Also you have to create an instance of this class by calling `$creator = new FGCaptchaCreator('testName');` Also, if you want to do it "properly" you may want to put "imagecreate" and "imagecolorallocate" inside the class also. Or create separate classes for them if you want to go OOP.

Comment: `FGCaptchaCreator()` __is not__ a constructor for `FGCaptchaCreator` since php8.

Comment: @u_mulder Ah yes, too much Java in my brain, you are completely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rename `function FGCaptchaCreator($captcha_var_name)` to `function __construct($captcha_var_name)`, because since php8.0 methods named same as class are **no longer** considered as constructors.

Also as `var` is an outdated language construct I would also add visibility to each property. And if it's clear from code - type-hint properties also, e.g.:

```
class FGCaptchaCreator extends FG_CaptchaHandler
{
    protected $image;
    protected int $width;
    protected int $height;
    // etc
```

Visibility and return type-hints for methods should be added too:

```
public function __construct($captcha_var_name)
public function Create(): bool
```